# redirect_to admin_url rails throws undefined local variable or method `admin_path' for #<SessionsController:0x75969f356028>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a very simple app which has a login logic in rails. This was derived from the depot example given in the book "The pragmatic programmers-Agile web development with rails". I have a session controller here that looks like this:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize
  def new
  end

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:name], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to admin_url
    else
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "Invalid user/password combination"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Logged out"
  end

end
```

When I enter the login information on website, I get the following error:
undefined local variable or method `admin_url' for #

When I enter the wrong creds I correctly get redirected to the login_url page. My admin view (app/views/admin/index.html.erb)looks like this:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>

It's <%= Time.now %>
We have <%= pluralize(@total_orders, "lab") %>.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `admin_url` is created by Rails if you have a route named `admin` (with the option `:as =>` in the `routes.rb`, or with `resources`). Use `rake routes` to check your routes: the name of the route (if exists) is in the first column. Surely your problem is that this route does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 
`get 'admin' => 'admin#index'`
to your routes.rb